# audio data, how to get tabular data from audio data python

Tags: python, audio, mfcc

I currently working with audio data. my target now to prepare the audio data in term of tabular data therefore I can perform analysis and ML.
anyone can help how to transform audio data into tabular data, for example MFCC features.

my question:

1. how to transform audio data to tabular data, MFCC features

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! As well as skimming [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I'd recommend looking at the [results for your question tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%2baudio%2bmfcc?tab=Votes)

Comment: MFCCs are not tabular data, it is a time-series. If one does summarization over time, then one can get some values that are 1-1 with your input audio, and might be called tabular.